# Qt slots - Different speeds sender/receiver - prevent queueing up data

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt-signals

I have two rather independent threads running.
One generates data and one contains some display logic.

I transmit data via some

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(processor, "newData");
```

on the generator side.
(processor is some QObject that is part of a Widget).

My data generation thread may be faster than the other one and everything gets pretty slow.
Displaying old data is meaningless in my use case so i do not want that the `invokeMethod` calls queue up.
Further invokes should be ignored or - at best - only the latest invoke should be executed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It sounds as if you might want to invert things slightly.  Currently you have the producer *pushing* data to the consumer regardless of whether or not the consumer is ready.  Why not have the consumer *pull* the latest complete data from the producer as and when it's ready?

Comment: The intuitive approach is to make it bidirectional messages,  _sender_ receives a ready sync message from _receiver_ and transmits only thereafter

Comment: If you want to keep push/pull model then you can have signal that emits something like dataReady signal; in your consumer thread slot for this signal will just set internal isReady flag (e.g. of type std::atomic<bool> to avoid concurrency issues). Your consumer can then query the latest data from consumer whenever it's ready to consume next batch.

Answer (score 0):

The `newData` method should do nothing but update the data record to be displayed, using a zero-cost-copy container (implicitly shared) and request a widget update. The widget update should then take the most recent data and display it.